# Error in minifed version of controller - angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp

I am working on `angularjs` and `node.js`.

#### Problem:

I am getting following error in **minified version** of controller(Angular Controller js file). But it is working in the normal version.

#### Error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/unpr?p0=eProvider%20%3C-%20e
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:8080/assets/lib/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:6:450
at http://localhost:8080/assets/lib/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:36:202
at Object.c [as get] (http://localhost:8080/assets/lib/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:34:305)
at http://localhost:8080/assets/lib/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:36:270
at c (http://localhost:8080/assets/lib/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:34:305)
at d (http://localhost:8080/assets/lib/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:35:6)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8080/assets/lib/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:35:165)
at http://localhost:8080/assets/lib/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:67:419
at link (http://localhost:8080/assets/lib/js/angularjs/angular-route.js:907:26) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

**I am using [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-uglify) to minify the controller**

#### Code

```
gulp.task('buildControllerScript', function(){
   return gulp.src(paths.controllers)
        .pipe(concat('controllers.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/dist/controllers/'))
        .pipe(rename('controllers.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/dist/controllers/'));
 });
```

#### Note:

Seems to be something wrong while uglify.

I cannot expose the controller code due to privacy rules

Any suggestion will be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Angular's dependency injection depends on the names of your function parameters, you either need to use [dependency annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) or replace the uglify gulp plugin with [gulp-ng-annotate](https://github.com/Kagami/gulp-ng-annotate).

Comment: FYI, I used to use dependency annotation, it made everything ugly, violated DRY and was a pain in the neck for testing (even using ng-mock). I switched to ng-annotate and been *much* happier